# Como funciona e como usar a função Reprex do R?

Tags: r, tidyverse

Em pesquisas aqui mesmo no SOpt vi sugestões de exemplos reprodutíveis. Um deles foi a função `reprex()`, pesquisei sobre e vi que seu uso é especifico para HTML, GitHub e aqui no Stack Overflow. Mas ainda não entendi como funciona.

Segui os passos em [reprex](https://reprex.tidyverse.org/), mas o R me traz uma mensagem de erro:

```
install.packages("reprex")
library(reprex)

(y <- 1:4)
mean(y)

reprex()

Rendering reprex...
Error: callr subprocess failed: <text>:18:7: '/' inesperado
17: #+ reprex-body
18: https:/
          ^
```

O que estou fazendo de errado? Como funciona e como usar a função `reprex` do R?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## O que é o `reprex`

O `reprex` é o apelido "exemplo reprodutível", inglês.

A ideia do pacote e da função `reprex` é rodar o código em um ambiente "novo" e "limpo", assim como ocorrerá com quem tentar reproduzir seu exemplo/problema.

Desta forma, a simples produção de um `reprex` já é ela mesma a garantia de que o exemplo em questão é reprodutível.

## Como usar

### 1. Ctrl + c

Há várias formas para usar o `reprex`. Uma das que mais gosto é copiar o código e rodar `reprex::reprex()`. Quando o `reprex` é usado sem argumentos ele verifica se há algum código no seu "crtl + c" e, havendo, ele usa para criar o exemplo reprodutível.

Infelizmente esta alternativa não é tão reprodutível assim e não consigo criar um reprex desta forma de usar o `reprex()`.

### 2. Dentro de chaves {}

Outra alternativa é colocar o código que será rodado como primeiro argumento do `reprex()` envolto em chaves (`{}`). Realizando seu exemplo e rodando

```
library(reprex)

reprex({
  (y <- 1:4)
  mean(y)
})
```

Teríamos o pedaço a baixo como resultado.

```r
(y <- 1:4)
#> [1] 1 2 3 4
mean(y)
#> [1] 2.5
```

<sup>Created on 2020-01-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

## Para que se dar ao trabalho?

A vantagem de usar o `reprex()` é que ele evidencia prontamente erros que fariam com que quem for te ajudar com o problema desista de tentar. Um bom exemplo é aquele em que se  esquece de compartilhar os dados usados para reproduzir o problema.

Neste exemplo você poderia compartilhar apenas o pedaço de código

```
mean(meus_dados$y)
```

E ainda que isso funcione para você não vai funcionar para mais ninguém. Isso acontece porque esse código depende do ambiente em que ele foi rodado e ninguém mais tem acesso a esse ambiente.

Se você colocar apenas essa mesma linha dentro do reprex,

```
reprex({mean(meus_dados$y)})
```

O resultado será:

```r
mean(meus_dados$y)
#> Error in mean(meus_dados$y): objeto 'meus_dados' não encontrado
```

<sup>Created on 2020-01-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Com isso você já saberá de antemão que deve readequar seu código para que o exemplo contenha todos os elementos que permitam que ele seja reproduzido em um outro contexto ou ambiente.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela resposta @Tomás Barcellos.

Comment: Só mais uma pergunta, eu testei no R e o Reprex abriu a representação do código em uma nova janela do browser. Como posso aplicá-lo aqui no Stack Overflow?

Comment: Ele já vai para o "control + v". Mas se não der certo, pode copiar e colar o código que você jogou no reprex.