# Como inserir os p-valores no summary do comando mtachit no R

Tags: r

Estou utilizando o comando matchit. Quando aplico a função summary, gostaria que, além das médias e da diferença entre os grupos tratamento e controle, o programa me indicasse se essas diferenças são significativas (e o nível de significância). Alguém sabe algum comando específico para isso? Segue o código utilizado e a saída:

```
X<-matchit (beneficiario ~ sexo+Idaderesp+presencaconj+escolaridade+ocup,        data = p,
            method = "nearest",replace =(TRUE),            estimand = "ATT")
summary(X)

Summary of Balance for All Data:
              Means Treated Means Control Std. Mean Diff. Var. Ratio eCDF Mean eCDF Max
distance             0.5152        0.4883          0.3417     0.9061    0.0852   0.1417
sexo1                0.4216        0.3758          0.0928          .    0.0458   0.0458
sexo2                0.5784        0.6242         -0.0928          .    0.0458   0.0458
Idaderesp           49.3707       53.0032         -0.2511     0.8610    0.0471   0.1146
presencaconj         0.6261        0.5553          0.1463          .    0.0708   0.0708
escolaridade0        0.1496        0.2043         -0.1536          .    0.0548   0.0548
escolaridade1        0.5497        0.5665         -0.0337          .    0.0168   0.0168
escolaridade2        0.1074        0.0938          0.0441          .    0.0136   0.0136
escolaridade3        0.1496        0.1066          0.1205          .    0.0430   0.0430
escolaridade4        0.0438        0.0288          0.0729          .    0.0149   0.0149
ocup                 2.5084        2.7564         -0.2087     0.6146    0.0519   0.1006


Summary of Balance for Matched Data:
              Means Treated Means Control Std. Mean Diff. Var. Ratio eCDF Mean eCDF Max Std. Pair Dist.
distance             0.5152        0.5152          0.0002     0.9977    0.0005   0.0048          0.0014
sexo1                0.4216        0.3994          0.0451          .    0.0223   0.0223          0.3383
sexo2                0.5784        0.6006         -0.0451          .    0.0223   0.0223          0.3383
Idaderesp           49.3707       49.9706         -0.0415     0.9521    0.0103   0.0326          0.4293
presencaconj         0.6261        0.6523         -0.0543          .    0.0263   0.0263          0.2746
escolaridade0        0.1496        0.1408          0.0245          .    0.0088   0.0088          0.2922
escolaridade1        0.5497        0.5672         -0.0352          .    0.0175   0.0175          0.2111
escolaridade2        0.1074        0.0931          0.0462          .    0.0143   0.0143          0.3443
escolaridade3        0.1496        0.1671         -0.0491          .    0.0175   0.0175          0.2900
escolaridade4        0.0438        0.0318          0.0583          .    0.0119   0.0119          0.2139
ocup                 2.5084        2.4893          0.0161     0.8768    0.0180   0.0493          0.4699

Percent Balance Improvement:
              Std. Mean Diff. Var. Ratio eCDF Mean eCDF Max
distance                 99.9       97.7      99.4     96.6
sexo1                    51.4          .      51.4     51.4
sexo2                    51.4          .      51.4     51.4
Idaderesp                83.5       67.2      78.2     71.5
presencaconj             62.9          .      62.9     62.9
escolaridade0            84.0          .      84.0     84.0
escolaridade1            -4.3          .      -4.3     -4.3
escolaridade2            -4.9          .      -4.9     -4.9
escolaridade3            59.3          .      59.3     59.3
escolaridade4            20.0          .      20.0     20.0
ocup                     92.3       73.0      65.3     51.0

Sample Sizes:
              Control Treated
All           1248.      1257
Matched (ESS)  294.29    1257
Matched        478.      1257
Unmatched      770.         0
Discarded        0.         0
```

Comment: Olá. Bem-vinda ao StackOverflow em português. Você pode nos oferecer um [exemplo reprodutível](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/432041/43953)?

Comment: Você sabe se o tipo de análise que está fazendo usa valor de *p* como critério? Não parece ser o caso.